# Como obter os registro de log do método `CakeLog::write()`?

Tags: php, log, cakephp-2

Eu estou estudando sobre os `logs` do `cakephp` e no meu código eu adicionei a seguinte linha para todas as ações de `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE` do meu sistema de `crud`.

```
Cakelog::write('debug', 'mensagem de exemplo de log!');
```

E agora eu quero saber como eu posso ver os registros de `logs` que são gerados por esse método `CakeLog::write()`?

Desde já eu agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Andei pesquisando sobre o arquivo de registros de logs na documentação do `CakePHP`e achei um arquivo chamado `debug.log` no diretório em `./app/tmp/logs/` onde mostra os registros das ações do meu aplicativo.